# Curved Mesh with Transparent Texture Transparency Issue

Tags: materials, bezier-curves, eevee-render-engine, image

Sorry if this isn't particularly clear, I'm finding it a little difficult to even describe the problem I am facing!

I have a model in Blender where I am aiming to model a layer being peeled off a letter as can be seen in this image (I've annotated the image with letters).

[image: rendering problem]

The letter can be thought of as being composed as two letters cut out of paper atop one another.

The letter at the back has a surface which can be seen labeled A in the image.

In front of the first letter is a second letter which has materials on both sides. There is the material labeled B at the back and the material labeled C at the front.

I created these letters using the "Import Images as Planes" tool. The two sided letter is a mesh formed from two separate planes which I have attached together with faces between the two. The mesh is a rectangle but the images on each face are transparent around the letter so you can see through the mesh.

To achieve the peeling effect, I have used the curve modifier to curve the letter at the front. The problem I am facing is that material C appears to be being 'obscured' by the transparency of material B meaning that A is seen instead of C.

To illustrate the problem further, here are a number of stills from the animated peeling which shows what is happening.

[image: still 1]
[image: still 2]
[image: still 3]

Thank you, please let me know if I can provide any more information to make this clearer.

Comment: Could you tell us / include a tag.. which renderer you are using?

Comment: @RobinBetts Just added this, thank you. (I am only using Eevee as it is the default, I'm not tied to this). I am also using Blender 2.91.0 if it's relevant.

Comment: Interestingly, changing the render engine to Cycles does appear to fix the problem. Is there any way of working around this in Eevee?

Comment: I think this has come up before.. trying to find the question